# Random Turtle movement, bound in window

Tags: python, python-3.x, turtle-graphics

Created the program to randomize the movement of the turtle but cannot get it to break the loop once it touches a boundary (window). Tried a few solutions posted with similar questions but still no luck.

```
from turtle import Turtle, Screen
import random

def createTurtle(color, width):
    tempName = Turtle("turtle")
    tempName.speed("fastest")
    tempName.color(color)
    tempName.width(width)
    return tempName

def inScreen(screen, turt):

    min_x, max_x = -wn.window_width() / 2 , wn.window_width() / 2
    min_y, max_y = -wn.window_height() / 2 , wn.window_height() / 2

    turtleX, turtleY = turt.pos()

    while (min_x < turtleX < max_x) and (min_y < turtleY < max_y):
        turt.left(random.randrange(360))
        turt.fd(random.randrange(100))
        turtleX, turtleY = turt.pos()
        print(turtleX, ",", turtleY)


wn = Screen()

alpha = createTurtle("red", 3)

inScreen(wn, alpha)

wn.exitonclick()
```

Comment: You need to update `turtleX, turtleY = turt.pos()` inside the `while` loop.

Comment: @JohnnyMopp Ahh that makes sense... without updating it always refers to (0,0). Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The variables turtleX and turtleY are being used in your while condition, but you never reevaluate them within the loop.

This is why your print function only ever outputs `0.0 , 0.0`